# How to turn randon 0s & 1s to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am following a course where I made a program to print `'*'` for 1 and `' '` for 0.

I thought to turn a image to 0 and 1s. So I got it from a website so that I can print it with my own code. I've made another code for turning that un-formatted list into a formatted list the website gave the following result that I want to convert into list.

```
1000111111111110000111111111111111111111
1001111111111100000111111111111111111111
0001111000000000000011111111111111111111
0001110000000000000011111111111111111111
1000110000000000000011111111111111111111
1110000000110000000011111111111111111111
0000000000111000000011111111111111111111
0000100001110000000011111111111111111111
0001111111100000000011111111111111111111
0000011000000000000011111111111111111111
0000000110000000000011111111111111111111
1100000111000000000011111111111111111111
1110000000000000000011111111111111111111
1110000000000000000111111111111111111111
1111000000000000000111111111111111111111
1111000000000000000111111111111111111111
1111100000000000000111111111111111111111
1110100000000000001111111111111111111111
1110100000000000001111111111111111111111
1000000000000000000011111111111111111111
0000000000000000000011111111111111111111
0000000000000000000011111111111111111111
0000000000000000000011111111111111111111
0000000000000000000011111111111111111111
0000000000000000000011111111111111111111
0000000000000000000011111111111111111111
0000000000000000000011111111111111111111
0000000000000000000011111111111111111111
0000000000000000000011111111111111111111
0000011000000000000011111111111111111111
0000011100000000000011111111111111111111
0010011100000100000011111111111111111111
0100111100000000000011111111111111111111
0001111000000000000111111111111111111111
0011111000000000000111111111111111111111
0010110000011100000011111111111111111111
0000010100000000000111111111111111111111
0000000000000000001111111111111111111111
0000000000000000001111111111111111111111
```

So my code for converting it is:

```
img = '''1000111111111110000111111111111111111111
1001111111111100000111111111111111111111
0001111000000000000011111111111111111111
0001110000000000000011111111111111111111
1000110000000000000011111111111111111111
1110000000110000000011111111111111111111
0000000000111000000011111111111111111111
0000100001110000000011111111111111111111
0001111111100000000011111111111111111111
0000011000000000000011111111111111111111
0000000110000000000011111111111111111111
1100000111000000000011111111111111111111
1110000000000000000011111111111111111111
1110000000000000000111111111111111111111
1111000000000000000111111111111111111111
1111000000000000000111111111111111111111
1111100000000000000111111111111111111111
1110100000000000001111111111111111111111
1110100000000000001111111111111111111111
1000000000000000000011111111111111111111
0000000000000000000011111111111111111111
0000000000000000000011111111111111111111
0000000000000000000011111111111111111111
0000000000000000000011111111111111111111
0000000000000000000011111111111111111111
0000000000000000000011111111111111111111
0000000000000000000011111111111111111111
0000000000000000000011111111111111111111
0000000000000000000011111111111111111111
0000011000000000000011111111111111111111
0000011100000000000011111111111111111111
0010011100000100000011111111111111111111
0100111100000000000011111111111111111111
0001111000000000000111111111111111111111
0011111000000000000111111111111111111111
0010110000011100000011111111111111111111
0000010100000000000111111111111111111111
0000000000000000001111111111111111111111
0000000000000000001111111111111111111111

'''

i = 0
pyt_img = ''
for num in img:
    if i == 0:
        pyt_img += f'[{num}'
        i = i+1
    elif i >= 1 & i < 39:
        pyt_img += f',{num}'
        i = i + 1
    elif i >= 40:
        pyt_img += f'{num}]\n'
        i = 0


print(pyt_img)
```

The problem is that it never reaches `i = 40` so `i = 40` line never works.

Comment: I would have expected an error like `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`.

Comment: Without trying to improve your code: i will stay at 39, because your first elif block is only entered if i is 38 or less; and the last is entered only if i is 40 or more. There is no case for i = 39. Also: Do not use the bitwise and ('&'), use the logical and ('and'). So your second elif becomes: `elif i >= 1 and i < 40:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elif i >= 1 & i < 39:
        pyt_img += f',{num}'
        i = i + 1
```

This branch of code is only entered if `i` is bigger or equal to 1 and `i` is smaller than 39. This means if `i`  is 39 it will not enter, since 39 is not smaller than 39. Therefore it wont add 1 to `i` and `i` never reaches 40. If you use `elif i >= 1 and i <=39:` it should work correctly.

Comment: There's still the problem of using bitwise and. I just tried `i=40`, then `i >= 1 & i < 39` results in True; but `i >= 1 and i < 39` results in False.

Comment: This is not at all how the condition gets evaluated, because `&` has higher precedence than the comparison operators. See my answer for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Given your `img` string you could use `str.join` with a nested list comprehension to achieve this

```
>>> print('\n'.join(''.join('*' if i == '1' else ' ' for i in line) for line in img.split('\n')))
*   ***********    *********************
*  ***********     *********************
   ****             ********************
   ***              ********************
*   **              ********************
***       **        ********************
          ***       ********************
    *    ***        ********************
   ********         ********************
     **             ********************
       **           ********************
**     ***          ********************
***                 ********************
***                *********************
****               *********************
****               *********************
*****              *********************
*** *             **********************
*** *             **********************
*                   ********************
                    ********************
                    ********************
                    ********************
                    ********************
                    ********************
                    ********************
                    ********************
                    ********************
                    ********************
     **             ********************
     ***            ********************
  *  ***     *      ********************
 *  ****            ********************
   ****            *********************
  *****            *********************
  * **     ***      ********************
     * *           *********************
                  **********************
                  **********************
```

Answer (score 1):

You are performing a bit-wise and `&` operation instead of a logical `and`. Python utilizes the `and` keyword to do what you are suggesting.

In addition, you are excluding the `i == 39` case in your `if` statement, so `i` is never becoming 40. Modify your `if` statement to be inclusive, so `if i >= 1 and i <= 39`.

Comment: 'bitwise and' and 'logical and' bind with different priority. In this case, the results differ for i > 39.

Comment: In your first version of this answer, you said that using "bitwise and" or "logical and" should not make a difference in this case. Well, it does make a difference here; but since you edited it out, we could delete our comments.

Answer (score 1):

The bitwise `&` that you use in `elif i >= 1 & i < 39:` has a higher [precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than the comparison operators.

So, because of precedence, the condition gets evaluated as

```
elif i >= (1 & i) < 39:
```

and the comparison chaining makes it equivalent to

```
elif (i >= (1 & i))  and  ((1 & i) < 39):
```

`1 & i` is the bitwise and of `1` and `i`, it will be equal to the last bit of `i`, so 0 if `i` is even or 1 if `i` is odd.

So`i> (1 & i)` will always be `True`, as well as `(1 & i) < 39`. Your whole condition is always `True`.